# Microsoft bot framework LUIS node js getting error 400

Tags: node.js, botframework

Trying my hand at using Microsoft bot framework NodeJS and it seems to be giving me a -> POST Refresh access token failed with status code: 400 error when I try to run it in the botframework-emulator. Do any of you have a similar problem? Is this a bug with the framework itself or there is something I am missing?

Comment: Hey user3200361,

It's really hard to tell exactly what the problem is without some code snippets or screen caps. If you could include one or the other that would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Need some more detail, but a guess would be you havent removed the "&q=" from the end of your LUIS url ?